# How to make svn diff show remote changes?

Tags: svn, command-line

For Example, when I type

```
svn st --show-updates
```

I get

```
    *   1648648   project/file1
```

so I know that file1 has changed.

I don't want to update just find out what has changed.
When I type

```
svn diff project/file1
```

it shows nothing because the file has no local changes.

How to make svn diff show remote changes?

Answer (score 41):

simply ask svn to make the diff with the HEAD revision :

```
svn diff -r HEAD project/file1
```

Answer (score 3):

Most correct version of diff between unmodified WC and updated repo is expanded answer of Cédric

`svn diff -r BASE -r HEAD project/file1`

Comment: `svn diff -r BASE:HEAD project/file1` but `BASE` is default target so you don't need it.